# Failure in a cross-contract call

Tags: nearprotocol

In https://nomicon.io/RuntimeSpec/Scenarios/CrossContractCall.html describes a cross-contract (cross-shard) transaction. Here we have: *alice_near* -> *travel_agency* -> *hotel_near* -> *travel_agency*. What would happen if *hotel_near* fail (preferably step-by-step)?

Answer (score 1):

- At the point of failure we stop executing the Wasm contract;
- We subtract burnt gas (notice that it is not used gas) from the prepaid gas and issue a refund transaction towards Alice with the remaining gas;
- Since `hotel_near` did not create any promises we do not do anything related to promises, but if it had we would have dropped them without creating receipts;
- `travel_agency` is still getting called, but the callback result now indicates that the callee has failed (hopefully `travel_agency` developer has added a code to gracefully process this situation and e.g. rollback the entire reservation).

Please let me know if you need to elaborate on some parts in more detail.

Comment: Used gas is the gas which is used during the contract execution, correct? Why not to charge for it?